# orderBy not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create 3 group - priorty 1,2 and 3 and use orderBy:priorty expect each pushed task will goes into their group. But after I test with more data I found within each group there's strange behaviour, which they don't sort properly.

```
<input ng-model="taskName"/>
  <button ng-click="AddTask()">Push task</button>

    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:'priorty'">priorty {{task.priorty}} - {{task.taskName}}</li>
```

newly items got pushed not to the bottom but sometime to the top / middle, why is this happens?

try my demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/V5aIZcLbhiSfLy1vEWoe?p=preview

Comment: I don't anything wrong. Tasks are always ordered by priority. Do you mean that within a priority-group the tasks can have arbitrary order ?

Comment: Interesting, well obviously they all have the same priority of `1` so this doesn't seem like a `not working properly` situation. You could use a multiple sort: `orderBy:['priorty', 'taskName']`

Comment: Push each letter in the alphabet and note what happens when you push 'h'

Comment: Seems to happen when there are 9 elements with the same priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items are always in correct order according to `priority`.
Other than that there is no requirement (and no guarantee) regarding the order of items within the same priority.

If want to have a second level of ordering, you can pass a list of properties to the `orderBy` filter:

```
ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy:['priorty','taksName']"
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/05BHOIBVO6vfZJipIOTE?p=preview)**.

---

**Regarding the "why" of your question**
<sub>(why does the re-ordering take place if you only order by 'priority'):</sub>

It seems to be browser-specific. The same code on Firefox does not "reorder" the items after inserting the 9th item (as does Chrome).

<sub>If I were to take a guess, I'd say it has to do with the way each browser keeps some reference to elements (internally) and at which point they decide to do some rehashing.</sub>

Comment: That looks like a great solution!

Comment: better order with taskId? because it's link to backend, I always want the latest pushed item to be at the most bottom in each group.

Comment: You can order by any property you like. `taskId` makes indeed more sense, but I refrained from using in the example, because you don't seem to assign an ID to new tasks. In a "real" environment other properties would definitely be better fits (e.g. creation-date, due-date, ID etc)

Comment: my taskId is auto-increment, so I think it's best to use that, bro thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @user3522457: I added a short note on the "why". It seems to be browser-specific. (I also took a look at the source-code of Angular and couldn't find anything that would cause this in the implementation of `ngRepeat` - but I might have missed something.) BTW, feel free to also upvote the answer if you really liked it :)

Comment: @ExpertSystem so this solution is not perfect? broken after the 9th item inserted?

Comment: @user3522457: I lost you. What solution is not perfect ? Are you asking or are you saying that is broke after the 9th item ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem I saw your answer saying something like 9th, oh maybe I saw it wrong.. thanks again for ur help!